# Maximum Function nesting level error Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I get the following error:

*Container.php line 702: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!*

I already increased the max nested level Attribute in my PHP.ini to 500. But nothing changed after restarting services in wamp.
I use wamp and Laravel 5.2

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Do you have any recursion or infinite loop in the controller function you are trying to execute? show your code.

Comment: I added in each route file the necessary code

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //} for handling sessions.  I use laravels modular package, so in each module I have a own Route file . In each Route file I added this Middleware Route. Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It probably come from the web middleware, you can delete it from your route if not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, edit the file **php.ini** or **50-extension-xdebug.ini** and add the following: **xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250** to increase the value of '100' that comes by default.
And then restart the apache service.

Answer (score 0):

Set php ini in your bootstrap app file as following:

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 2048);
```